# Run Method In Thread And Get Returned Value

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method which I want to run it in a different thread.

```
{ ...

 string output = MyClass.MyMethod();
}
```

The `MyClass` Method returns a string and I need to get the output and also run this threaded.

How could I do this ?

Comment: Start [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: `Task.Run` is probably the simplest approach - but there's not much point in using another thread if you need to block until you get the response. Maybe now is a good time to learn about async/await.